# How to add LineFinal (falt) or WordFinal (fina) features to Garamond Premier Pro on XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, fontspec, opentype

I'm still familiarizing myself with XeLaTeX and the `fontspec` package. I would like to access the OpenType feature `LineFinal` or `WordFinal` with the Garamond Premier Pro font from Adobe.

For example, I would like to obtain the following when ending a line or a paragraph :

[image]

So I tried adding the `Contextuals=WordFinal` option to `\setmainfont` but instead I get the following :

[image]

and the console says this :

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Contextuals=WordFinal' (+fina) not available for font
* 'Garamond Premier Pro/BI' with script 'Latin' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************
```

which usually does not bother me because the same warning appears for `Historic`, `Rare` or `TeX` `Ligatures` options and they do work fine.

Here's the MWE for testing :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Rare,TeX,Historic}, Contextuals=WordFinal]{Garamond Premier Pro}

\begin{document}
It's easy to be polite.\smallskip

Next paragraph starts here.
\end{document}
```

To obtain the "e.end" of the first pic, instead of writing `polite` I wrote `polit\XeTeXglyph249` which works well. But it will become really tedious if I have to do this every time... Is there a simple solution?

**EDIT 1**

Seems that AGPPro doesn't feature the `fina` nor the `falt` features. Checked it using `otfinfo -f` on a terminal :

```
$ otfinfo -f /Library/Fonts/Garamond\ Premier\ Pro/GaramondPremrPro.otf 

aalt    Access All Alternates
c2sc    Small Capitals From Capitals
calt    Contextual Alternates
case    Case-Sensitive Forms
cpsp    Capital Spacing
dlig    Discretionary Ligatures
dnom    Denominators
frac    Fractions
hist    Historical Forms
kern    Kerning
liga    Standard Ligatures
lnum    Lining Figures
numr    Numerators
onum    Oldstyle Figures
ordn    Ordinals
ornm    Ornaments
pnum    Proportional Figures
salt    Stylistic Alternates
sinf    Scientific Inferiors
size    Optical Size
smcp    Small Capitals
ss01    Stylistic Set 1
ss02    Stylistic Set 2
ss03    Stylistic Set 3
ss04    Stylistic Set 4
subs    Subscript
sups    Superscript
tnum    Tabular Figures
zero    Slashed Zero
```

Any solutions?

*I would settle if I could at least use the feature at the end of paragraphs (as they may be the only places where I actually use the feature).*

Comment: @NilsL Good point... Why is this all so tricky?! Anyways what do you mean by `RawFeature`?

Comment: @NilsL Not again... I just switched from Lua to Xe because my font didn't work correctly when compiled with Lua (most of the features don't work). But maybe it's the sole solution here...

Comment: It's only tricky if you expect OpenType, in it's full range of features, to harmonize perfectly, out of the box, with a typesetting application designed decades before OpenType saw the light of day. InDesign users will find this not tricky at all, simply because the two were basically made for each other :)

Comment: @NilsL Just tried the RawFeature... it doesn't even care about it... Maybe the feature's missing.

Comment: okay, we should avoid an extended discussion here. I suggest you take a look the manual and the tech specs that Adobe supplied you with when they sent you the fonts. It should tell you what features are available and how to access them. It saves time to check that first. As far as I can [tell](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/garamond-premier/med/specs.html) from my desk, there is, e.g., no `fina` in Garamond Premier Pro.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't matter to you, but these sorts of 'stretched' letters were only used (sometimes) to fill out a line so that the line was properly justified, especially in manuscripts / early printings where the margins were narrow.  It might look odd to drop them in at the end of any paragraph whatsoever.  ... In other words, a 'manual' solution might be preferred since you will need to make an aesthetic judgment call in each case!

Comment: addendum: and used in rubrics and 'headers'.

Comment: @jrojasqu: jon is making an important point here, and what might be added is that, as consequence, these glyphs were, IIRC, never followed by a punctuation sign! I suggest you have a look at Late-Mediaeval and Renaissance manuscripts to get an idea of the standard usage of these things.

Comment: @NilsL Sure thing, where can I find some examples?

Comment: @jrojasqu -- a good place to browse is the 900 000+(!) digitalizations of manuscripts and incunabula editions at the [Bavarian State Library](http://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/index.html?c=digitale_sammlungen&l=en&projekt=).  The website is mostly in German, though I tried to give a link for the English versions.

Comment: + every decent library should have books on typography and its history. [Typophile](http://www.typophile.com) is a great resource, too. I suggest that, in addition, or even before you start working on squiggles and embellishments, you have a look at the [Elements (!) of Typographic Style.](http://www.amazon.fr/dp/0881792128) It's really worth every cent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following some comments, elements from another answers in this forum and a little research on typography, I found out that the features I wanted are only to be used in particular cases. These cases are not really abundant so the solution I propose can be used only when needed.

This solution involves the `\XeTeXglyph` function, which can be used to access a particular glyph that one can't specifically type with the keyboard. This means of course that a compilation using `XeLaTeX` is needed. (Or maybe I'm wrong?).

I added the following commands to the preamble :

```
\newcommand{\af}{\XeTeXglyph247}
\newcommand{\df}{\XeTeXglyph248}
\newcommand{\ef}{\XeTeXglyph249}
\newcommand{\hf}{\XeTeXglyph250}
\newcommand{\mf}{\XeTeXglyph251}
\newcommand{\nf}{\XeTeXglyph252}
```

and so on for every alternate glyph I wish to use. This way it is easier to call the alternate glyphs to "emulate" a `WordFinal` or `LineFinal` procedure simply calling `\af`, `\df`, `\ef`, etc, at the end of a word, sentence or paragraph :

[image]

**NOTE**

I did try to use the `RawFeature` options from the `fontspec` package to load the "Stylistic Sets".

For AGPPro these are the ones available :

```
ss01    Stylistic Set 1
ss02    Stylistic Set 2
ss03    Stylistic Set 3
ss04    Stylistic Set 4
```

But neither one of them had a `WordFinal` or `LineFinal` feature embedded.

Answer (score 9):

To summarize my answers scattered in the comments to your question:

**1.** The tech specs or manual that come with the font should include a list of what features the font has and how to access them. This list here [says](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/garamond-premier/med/specs.html) there is, for example, no `falt` or `fina` feature in Garamond Premier Pro. This would explain why what you're doing has no effect. `fontspec` can't do more than what's available in the font.

**2.** The word-final forms you're looking for might be available via a *different* feature tag, though. Consider this example using Minion:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[StylisticSet=2]{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
politee
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can [see](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/395646) from Minion Pro's feature file, this is, however, not the smart kind of *line*-end substitution you want.

```
feature ss02 {
    ignore sub @END_OFF' @WORD;
    sub @END_OFF' by @END_ON;
} ss02;
```

**3.** Whenever fontspec is giving you trouble accessing a feature that should be available, `RawFeature` might help. In addition to the font's documentation, Eddie Kohler's `otfinfo` is a useful tool to check what features a font has and what their tags are.

**4.** With Lua, fontspec is able to use OpenType feature files. You can [write](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_feature_file_syntax.html) your own to add custom substitution rules and other stuff.

**5.** Fancy things can be done using OpenType fonts. Not all of them can be done by all TeX engines. The fontspec manual provides information on what's possible in Xe and/or Lua respectively. When choosing an engine, other factors might be more important, though, than ease of access to line-end `subs.` Apart from that -- the more fancyness you want, the more likely it'll be that a system *other* than TeX will be a better choice, as fancyness isn't among the applications TeX was designed for IMHO.

Comment: You're right, I just checked what RawFeatures are available running `mtxrun --script fonts --info --list --name --pattern="*GaramondPremrPro*"` on a terminal. `fina` and `falt` **are not** there. Thanks anyways, I'll have to look for another solution though.